# How to fix a mixed encoding unicode object?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have this in python and it is driving me nuts. How can I fix (normalize) the encoding in this string:

```
u"wie wir sie lieben **\u2013** unkompliziert und am Puls der Zeit**\u201c**\nElegant, casual oder maritim, unsere Alltags-Looks sind so **viel\xe4fltig** wie unser Leben"
```

Martijn marked it as a duplicate question:
I need to ask once more. The above string contains both: \u2013 and \xe4f
Doesn't this indicate a mixed encoding. If yes, how can it be fixed?
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If I do `print()` on that string, Python can print it. So what exactly do you wish to change?

Comment: Don't confuse the `repr()` output with the actual contents. You already have the right value, there is nothing to fix here.

Comment: doesn't \u2013 and \xe4f in one string indicate a mixed encoding?

Comment: That is just a Unicode string.  You have code points U+2013 and U+00E4 in it.  Since U+00E4 is less than 256, Python shows it as `\xe4` (the f is the next character after the `\xe4`).